# Laravel where() and orderBy() on a relation table that's on an external server

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I need to use Laravel *where()* and *orderBy()* methods. The problem is that the data i need to filter and order comes from a **relation** that is on an **external server** / another host database (PostgreSQL).

What i've tried:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $productforms = $this->productform
            ->select('product_forms.*')
            ->with('product')
            ->join('types', 'product_forms.type_id', '=', 'types.id')
            ->where('product.description', 'ILIKE', '%sugar%');
            // ...
    }
```

Tried it too:

```
$rawquery = DB::table('product_forms')
    ->join('testing.base.products as db2','product_forms.product_id','=','db2.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('form_title as title'))
    ->first();
```

I've searched in so many topics, but didn't found nothing exactly similar.

Laravel error message for above second attempt:

```
"""
SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "testing.base.product"
LINE 1: ...m_title as titulo from "product_forms" inner join "test...
                                                             ^ (SQL: select form_title as titulo from "product_forms" inner join "testing"."base"."product ▶
"""
```

Laravel error message for above first attempt:

```
"""
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"
LINE 1: ...on "product_forms"."type_id" = "types"."id" where "products"...
                                                             ^ (SQL: select "product_forms".* from "product_forms" inner join "types" on "product_forms"."type_id" = "types"."id" where "products"."description"::text ILIKE %sugar%) ◀
"""
```

Local server model productForm:

```
class ProductForm extends Model implements Auditable
{

    protected $table='product_forms';

    protected $connection = 'localserver';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 
        'product_id', 
        'type_id'
        // ...
    ];

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

}
```

External server model Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $connection='externalserver';

    protected $table='base.products';

    protected $fillable = [
       'id',
       'description',
       'attributes'
       // ...
    ];
    // ...

}
```

Sample Env structure:

```
DB_CONNECTION=localserver
DB_HOST_PG=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_PG=5432

DB_CONNECTIONK=externalserver
DB_HOST_PGK=externaldomain.com
DB_PORT_PGK=5432
```

Conf/database.php connections:

```
'connections' => [

    'localserver' => [
        'read' => [
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_PG', '127.0.0.1'),
        ],
        'write' => [
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_PG_WRITE', '127.0.0.1'),
        ],
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_PG', '5432'),
        // ...
    ],

    'externalserver' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_PGK', 'externaldomain.com'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_PGK', '5432'),
        // ...
    ]

]
```

Thanks! any hint will help me

Comment: You've said that a problem occurs, but you haven't really described what actually happens. Are you getting error messages? Crashes? Are you able to do more simple queries that don't involve `where` or `orderBy`?

Comment: Have you given Laravel's query builder a go? You can specify connection name in the builder it self.  Have a look through this as well, could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955700/laravel-raw-query-using-a-specific-connection

Comment: You trying to join two tables in distinct databases? If you are trying this, you need to replicate the table that you are trying to do where and orderBy on your main database.

Comment: why are you creating model just use raw query for external db as you will not be able to create any relationship with it!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the message error, i've edited the question and there is bellow too:

"""
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"
LINE 1: ...on "product_forms"."type_id" = "types"."id" where "products"...
                                                             ^ (SQL: select "product_forms".* from "product_forms" inner join "types" on "product_forms"."type_id" = "types"."id" where "products"."description"::text ILIKE %sugar%) ◀
"""

@Spudley thanks

Comment: @user3532758 thanks! I will read the topic

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes unfortunatelly don't have permissions to clone the external table, also it's a huge amount of jsonb data, frequently updated.

Comment: @Spudley i can retrieve the data from two servers, through eager loading, but i can't use where() or orderBy() specifically. When i look the queries log from laravel, it's querying like the second table is on the same database and not on the external server. I've tryied to find for a raw "external sub-select", but PostgreSQL isn't able to do that.

Comment: @phpdroid thanks! i will try to use raw query on postgresql external server indeed, and join it on laravel

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the better solution yet, but temporarily I came to a workaround. My goal is to use where() to make a search filter for a list. The workaround i made was:

On the model, using a conditional local scope:

```
public function scopeSearchField($query, $search) {

        // retrieving the external cross-database data using where() on a closure inside eager loading/with() method

        if (!empty($search['product']) ) {
            $query->with(
                    [
                        'product' =>
                            function ($query) use($search){
                                $query->whereRaw(" public.unaccent('description')::text ILIKE public.unaccent('%{$search["product"]}%')::text");
                            }
                    ]);
        }

    }
```

On the controller:

```
$productforms = $this->productform
    ->select('product_forms.*')
    ->searchField($request->all());
```

On the view:

```
@forelse($productforms as $productform)
                @if($productform->product!= null)

                <tr>
                    <td>$productforms->title</td>
                    <td>$productforms->product->description</td>
                    <td>$productforms->...</td>
                    <td>$productforms->...</td>
                </tr>

                @endif
@endforelse
```